# How to Correctly Implement ffmpeg Complex Filters in Node.js for Image Processing?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

#### Problem:

I am trying to add filters and transitions between my image slideshow array, and am struggling to apply the proper filters. For example, I get errors like this:

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "ffmpeg exited with code 234: Failed to set value 'fade=type=in:start_time=0:duration=1,zoompan=z=zoom+0.002:d=120:x=if(gte(zoom,1.2),x,x+1):y=if(gte(zoom,1.2),y,y+1)' for option 'filter_complex': Invalid argument\nError parsing global options: Invalid argument\n",
  "trace": [
    "Error: ffmpeg exited with code 234: Failed to set value 'fade=type=in:start_time=0:duration=1,zoompan=z=zoom+0.002:d=120:x=if(gte(zoom,1.2),x,x+1):y=if(gte(zoom,1.2),y,y+1)' for option 'filter_complex': Invalid argument",
    "Error parsing global options: Invalid argument",
    "",
    "    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:182:22)",
    "    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)",
    "    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)"
  ]
}
```

#### Lambda Function Code:

```
 async function concat(bucketName, imageKeys) {
      const imageStreams = await Promise.all(
        imageKeys.map(async (key, i) => {
          const command = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: key });
          const response = await s3.send(command);
          // Define the temporary file path based on the index
          const tempFilePath = `/tmp/${i}.png`;
    
          // Write the image data to the temporary file
          await fs.writeFile(tempFilePath, response.Body);
    
          // Return the file path to be used later
          return tempFilePath;
        })
      );
    
      // Create a file list content with durations
      let fileContent = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < imageStreams.length; i++) {
        fileContent += `file '${imageStreams[i]}'\nduration 1\n`;
    
        // Check if it's the last image, and if so, add it again
        if (i === imageStreams.length - 1) {
          fileContent += `file '${imageStreams[i]}'\nduration 1\n`;
        }
      }
    
      // Define the file path for the file list
      const fileListPath = "/tmp/file_list.txt";
    
      // Write the file list content to the file
      await fs.writeFile(fileListPath, fileContent);
    
      try {
        await fs.writeFile(fileListPath, fileContent);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error writing file list:", error);
        throw error;
      }
    
      // Create a complex filter to add zooms and pans
      // Simplified filter example
  let complexFilter = [
    // Example of a fade transition
    {
      filter: 'fade',
      options: { type: 'in', start_time: 0, duration: 1 },
      inputs: '0:v', // first video stream
      outputs: 'fade0'
    },
    // Example of dynamic zoompan
    {
      filter: 'zoompan',
      options: {
        z: 'zoom+0.002',
        d: 120, // duration for this image
        x: 'if(gte(zoom,1.2),x,x+1)', // dynamic x position
        y: 'if(gte(zoom,1.2),y,y+1)' // dynamic y position
      },
      inputs: 'fade0',
      outputs: 'zoom0'
    }
    // Continue adding filters for each image
  ];

  let filterString = complexFilter
    .map(
      (f) =>
        `${f.filter}=${Object.entries(f.options)
          .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
          .join(":")}`
    )
    .join(",");
    
      let filterString = complexFilter
        .map(
          (f) =>
            `${f.filter}=${Object.entries(f.options)
              .map(([key, value]) => `${key}=${value}`)
              .join(":")}`
        )
        .join(",");
    
      console.log("Filter String:", filterString);
    
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ffmpeg()
          .input(fileListPath)
          .complexFilter(filterString)
          .inputOptions(["-f concat", "-safe 0"])
          .outputOptions("-c copy")
          .outputOptions("-c:v libx264")
          .outputOptions("-pix_fmt yuv420p")
          .outputOptions("-r 30")
          .on("end", () => {
            resolve();
          })
          .on("error", (err) => {
            console.error("Error during video concatenation:", err);
            reject(err);
          })
          .saveToFile("/tmp/output.mp4");
      });
    }
```

#### Filter String Console Log:

```
Filter String: fade=type=in:start_time=0:duration=1,zoompan=z=zoom+0.002:d=120:x=if(gte(zoom,1.2),x,x+1):y=if(gte(zoom,1.2),y,y+1)
```

#### Questions:

1. What is the correct syntax for implementing complex filters like zoompan and fade in ffmpeg when used in a Node.js environment?
2. How do I ensure the filters are applied correctly to each image in the sequence?
3. Is there a better way to dynamically generate these filters based on the number of images or their content?

Any insights or examples of correctly implementing this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `zoompan=options=[object Object]` doesn't look right.  What is the output of `console.log(filterString)`?

Comment: Hi James, it is `Filter String: zoompan=`. I have a larger goal of knowing where all these settings are and how to apply them, because I can't seem to find the docs to support my progress.

Comment: Well it is when you run this code with an empty options object, but your error message shows that you are providing some options inside complexFilter.options, and those are not being correctly transformed into the filterString.

Comment: The ffmpeg filter docs are [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html)

Comment: Thank you. I've made the console logs align with the lambda code now for more accuracy.

Comment: So is it your fade filter or your zoompan filter that breaks?  Try them individually.  The zoompan params have quotes in them in the doc examples, you seem to be missing those, check https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#zoompan

Answer (score 0):

After analysing the documentation, I have created successfully a zoom and pan effect as intended:

```
    async function createZoomAndPanEffect(imagePath) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          ffmpeg(imagePath)
            .complexFilter([
              {
                // Start zoomed in at the left (x=0), centered vertically, and pan to the right
                filter: "zoompan",
                options: "z=1.2:d=125:x='min(x+1,iw-(iw/zoom))':y='(ih/zoom-ih)/2'",
                outputs: 'v1'
              },
              {
                // Fade out effect at the end of the video
                filter: "fade",
                options: {
                  type: "out",
                  start_time: "4", // Start fade out 1 second before the end
                  duration: "1", // Duration of fade out
                },
                inputs: 'v1'
              },
         

   ])
        .outputOptions(["-c:v libx264", "-pix_fmt yuv420p", "-r 30"])
        .on("end", () => resolve())
        .on("error", (err) => {
          console.error("Error during video processing:", err);
          reject(err);
        })
        .saveToFile("/tmp/output.mp4");
    });
  }
```